# Set Title to TableViewController - Beginner

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIViewController called `MyViewController`. When I click on a button, I go to another UITableVIewController.

The code I use to navigate to this TableviewController is :

```
UIStoryboard *s = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *v = [s instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tbviewc"];
v.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:v animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I have set the NavigationController to this `TableViewController`.

Now I want to set the title for it. How can I do this?

Nb: This is a storyboard application.

None of the following worked :

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"the title";
```

Comment: `[self setTitle:@"The Title"];` in the actual `UIViewController` instance, somewhere around either `–viewDidLoad` or `–viewWillAppear:` methods, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `self.navigationController` is nil
You should do this:

```
    UIViewController *v = [s instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tbviewc"];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:s];
    v.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Then try to use `self.title = @"title";` in `UIViewController`(v)

Or not nil, try this:

```
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,40,100)];
    title.text = @"title";
    UINavigationController *nav = [UINavigationController new];
    nav.navigationItem.titleView = title;
```

Comment: It's the first point you made. OP never creates a new nav controller for the modal, they're simply presenting a VC without the nav controller.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
v.title = @"the title"
```

v is your `UIViewController` object.